# Xpath in IE11 not working

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium in IE 11 with C# to automate some task. I am able to open URL in IE and click on some button but i stuck in one problem like other xpath i click on one image link but it always show xpath not found.

[image]

Here is the HTML code of the link 
I tried it with both ID name src etc but no success.

```
    <li>   
    <INPUT disabled id=ucTicketDetail1_btnClose title="- Cannot close    
    due to     CM stage. Ticket must be in CM Approved or Preproduction Approved     stage.&#10;-
  You don't have permission to close.&#10;- No longer editable."      style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; 
    BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH:  ; BORDER-TOP-    WIDTH: 0px"    src="../images/tasks_disabled.gif" type=image     name=ucTicketDetail1$btnClose>
    <li>
```

Selenium Code

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='ucTicketDetail1_btnClose']")).Click();
```

Please help how could I write xpath for this as this application only open in IE.

here is the extended code with style

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
LI {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
LI {
    list-style: none;
}
LI {
    float: left;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}
LI {
    float: left;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}
UL {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
UL {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
}
UL {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
}
DIV {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.TicketDetailHeaderRight {
    float: right;
}
.TicketDetailHeader {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0 5px 5px;
    min-height: 15px;
}
.SectionBody {
    margin: 5px;
}
.Section {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
FORM {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
BODY {
    color: #000;
}
BODY {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
BODY {
    font: 13px/1.231 arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;
    font-size: ;
    font: x-small;
}
BODY {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 83%;
    line-height: normal;
}
HTML {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 83%;
    line-height: normal;
}
INPUT {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
INPUT {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}
</style>
</head>

<BODY><FORM id=formTicketDetail method=post name=formTicketDetail action=wfTicketDetail.aspx?TicketId=C110041540 _events="[object Object]">
<DIV class=Section>
<DIV class=SectionBody>
<DIV class=TicketDetailHeader>
<DIV id=ucTicketDetail1_divBtnBar class=TicketDetailHeaderRight>
<DIV id=ucTicketDetail1_updatePanelPostSaveActions>
<DIV id=ucTicketDetail1_divPostSaveActions class=PostSaveActions>
<UL>
<LI><INPUT disabled id=ucTicketDetail1_btnClose title="- Cannot close due to CM stage. Ticket must be in CM Approved or Preproduction Approved stage.&#10;- You don't have permission to close.&#10;- No longer editable." style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px" src="../images/tasks_disabled.gif" type=image name=ucTicketDetail1$btnClose> </LI></UL></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></FORM></BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how the page is or link to real webpage

Comment: i will post screenshot of webpage as this application work only in internal  network

Answer (score 0):

i solve this question , actually image button is located under 2 iframe. I switch to Iframe then it start working. 
Here is the code

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("wfMainIFrame");
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame("wfCaseIFrame");

        string atb = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='ucTicketDetail1_btnClose']")).GetAttribute("disabled");
        string title = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='ucTicketDetail1_btnClose']")).GetAttribute("title");
```

Thanks for the help.